# Was "To Be or Not to Be" inspired by the "The Producers"?

Tags: the-producers, to-be-or-not-to-be

I vaguely remember an interview with Mel Brooks where he stated that *Spaceballs* was inspired by the *History of the World: Part I* end scene of Jews in Space.

This made me wonder if *To Be or Not to Be* came from a similar desire to actually show the fictional play "Funny Boy", from *The Producers*, to audiences. Has Mel Brooks ever stated that this was actually the inspiration for *To Be or Not to Be*?

Comment: This question could be a good fit for this site if you slightly re-word it. It is unclear what connection you are referring to right now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I additionally removed the open-ended question at the end since that is really too broad. In its current form this seems to be a reasonable and well-scoped question. Reopened. +1

Comment: In some material about Blazing Saddles I think Mel said that Producers came from that idea of making so offensive play it would flop on purpose.

Comment: To be or not to be is a remake of an older film.

Answer (score 1):

"Funny Boy" is a show referenced in the opening number of the 2001 Broadway musical version of *The Producers*.  Mel Brooks’ film *To Be or Not to Be* was made eighteen years prior in 1983, and is a remake of a 1942 film of the same name, starring Jack Benny and Carole Lombard.  Given the dates, "Funny Boy" could not have inspired *To Be or Not to Be*.

Comment: Are you saying "Funny Boy" was not part of the 1967 film version of *The Producers*? That might be a clarification worth adding (as it would also show that you're aware of the '67 film's existence).

Comment: I am aware of the original 1967 film.   I cannot find anything that indicates "Funny Boy" was mentioned in it.  Certainly, the original and the Broadway show (and subsequent film) differ in how they begin.  It's possible "Funny Boy" is one of the scripts Max and Leo reject, but I don't believe so.  I hope to confirm that this evening.

Answer (score 1):

Funny Boy was based on Hamlet, according to the 2005 remake of [*The Producers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Producers_(2005_film)).  There was no reference to any specific play in the [1967 version of the film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Producers_(1967_film)) which is comparable; in so much as there was no specific play that flopped at the beginning of the film.

[*To Be Or Not To Be* (1983)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Be_or_Not_to_Be_(1983_film)) was actually a direct remake of the [1942 film of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Be_or_Not_to_Be_(1942_film)), to the point of actually reusing some of the same dialogue.  As such, they couldn't possibly be related.